# Finding size from SKUs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

```
A2: ad-m-trxswft-r2-hs-bbb-12 
A3: mr-drifter-9.5 
A4: arc-m-thoriumar-hdy-g2-hb-xl 
A5: arc-w-satoro-arz-ls-bk-m 
A6: arc-m-XS
```

---

```
B2: 12
B3: 9.5
B4: XL
B5: M
B6: XS
```

I would like to figure out how to get the size: `B2,B3,B4,B5,B6` from the end of `SKUs` by using Excel formula.

Thank you

Jun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=upper(trim(right(substitute(a2, "-", rept(" ", len(a2))), len(a2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach.

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","|", LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","")))))
```

[image]